# Node-Red on IBM cloud issue

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm trying to setup Node-RED starter application but I can't find it in the catalog in IBM cloud

According to [this](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-node-red-starter-application/) it should be there.
I tried searching for "node-RED" in the catalog but nothing was returned as result

I have a pay-as-you-go-account

Comment: Unfortunately this question is probably off topic for Stack Overflow, as it appears to be more a question directly to IBM about if they have removed Node-RED from their catalogue.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that IBM have removed all Starter Kits on February 18

https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/announcements/deprecation-of-ibm-cloud-starter-kits

Comment: Does this mean I can no longer use Node-Red with IBM cloud ?

Comment: There are probably other ways to run it on IBM Cloud e.g. by deploying the Node-RED Docker container. But it means there is probably no simple "Click to deploy" solution any more. There are alternative cloud providers that offer Node-RED hosting e.g. [FlowForge](https://flowforge.com) (I work for FlowForge)

Answer (score 1):

node-red IBMCloud starter kits were based on CloudFoundry, which will be deprecated completely in June 2023: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-deprecation

They switched to Operators based deployments. You can still deploy node-red on IBM Cloud free of charge, as a Red-Hat Operator: https://marketplace.redhat.com/en-us/products/node-red-operator

You don't have to use a red hat open shift cluster, the operator will also work on a regular Kubernetes cluster.

IMHO the provisioning experience is way better than the old one based on Cloud Foundry, but the documentation and examples are less clear...

Comment: Not very familiar with all that clusters and containers but I see that the free Kubernetes cluster in IBM cloud expires after 30 days. Doesn't look like there is a viable free option anymore. So if I'm going to pay for a service then I would try to find something simpler to host my NodeRED app in a cloud.

Comment: if you want to host a stable node-red server, then the best option would be flow-forge IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The probably fastest and easiest way to get Node-RED deployed on IBM Cloud nowadays is to use [Code Engine](https://cloud.ibm.com/codeengine/overview)

From the [Code Engine](https://cloud.ibm.com/codeengine/overview) starter page you can specify a Docker image of Node-Red in the "Run a container image" section of the page, for instance `nodered/node-red`, and hit the "Start Creating" button.

The next page is asking you to specify a project name. Once you have specified the project name and are happy with the other options you can create a Code Engine application that will run the container image that you have specified.

Once the container image is downloaded and started you can access it via an URL provided by IBM Cloud.